# Finding a subvariety that is finite over the target.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

Given a surjective homomorphism of abelian varieties like $f:A\rightarrow B$ where $\text{dim}(A)>\text{dim}(B)$, is it possible to find a subvariety $Z$ of $A$ such that restriction of $f$ to $Z$ induces a finite surjective morphism $f|_Z:Z\rightarrow B$? (this is equivalent to asking whether there is a cycles $Z$ such that $f_*[Z]$ is an integer in the grothendieck group of $B$)

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** "(this is equivalent to asking whether there is a cycles Z such that $f_∗[Z]$ is an integer in the grothendieck group of $B$)"

**Comment:** If $f: A \rightarrow B$ is a proper morphism of abelian varieties, there is an induced push forward map at the level of Chow groups

$$f_*: A_k(A) \rightarrow A_k(B)$$

and for any cycle $[Z]\in A_k(A)$ it follows $f_*[Z]\in A_k(B)$ is an algebraic cycle and not an integer. The group $A_k(B)$ is an abelian group that is not finitely generated in general. Similarly for the Grothendieck group: The push forward will be a class $\sum_i n_i[E_i]\in K_0(B)$. You must specify what you are talking about.

It seems you want $B$ to be irreducible with $d:=dim(B)$ and hence $A_d(B)$ is generated by $[B]$.

There is if $B:=B_1 \cup \cdots \cup B_l$ are the irreducible components of $B$
with $dim(B_i)=d$ for all $i$ an isomorphism of abelian groups

$$A_d(B)\cong\mathbb{Z}[B_1]\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}[B_l]\cong \mathbb{Z}^l,$$

hence you may not in general identify $A_d(B)$ and $\mathbb{Z}$.

**Note:** There is the "etale overing lemma" (Mumford, Abelian Varieties page 167) saying that if $f:Y \rightarrow X$ is an etale cover with $X$ an abelian variety, then $Y$ has the structure of abelian variety and $f$ is a separable isogeny. In your case this puts conditions on $Z$ if the induced map $f_Z$ is etale.

Comment: Yes the pushforward of a cycle is defined in the following way: If the restriction of $f$ to the cycle is not finite then it is zero, if it is finite then it is the image of the cycle multiplied by the generic degree of the finite map. So if a cycle is finite on the whole target, then its pushforward should be the whole target times an integer which basically means it is an integer or codimension 0 cycle.